# Serialize certain input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get / serialize certain input with jQuery.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="car[303][is_good]" value="1">
```

How can I get all cars with jQuery?

Comment: Put them in a form and call `serialize()`?

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

He says he already solved it:

> I solved using this $('input[name^="car"]').serialize()